# Grid doesn't stretch inside ListPicker item

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have Grid inside ListPicker full mode item. Grid has two columns. First column should be left-aligned and second right-aligned.

Unfortunately this template doesn't work as expected:

```
<DataTemplate x:Name="ListFullModeItemTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Description}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Second TextBlock doesn't align to right.

When I set Grid Width property to specific value i.e.

```
<Grid Width="700">
    ...
</Grid>
```

then it works, but I can't do it because user can rotate phone to Portrait/Landscape.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
I also had the same problem in ListBox. 
I fixed it by adding:

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                 </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

I can't use this in ListPicker because it doesn't have ItemContainerStyle element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set your grid 's width.

and change it by +=:
 OrientationChanged += new EventHandler(SecondPage_OrientationChanged);

Comment: I can no longer verify your reply but I assume it is valid.

Answer (score 0):

try adding `TextAlignment="Right"`

Comment: Nothing changed. I also tried adding HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" to Grid but either doesn't work.